# Javascript regex searching for calendar events

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation where I need to take a sentence and check certain boxes and/or enter numbers into text inputs.

The boxes are things like..

- every day
- ever week
- every month

So I'm not sure if it would be better to use different regex objects to search for the different situations, or if I should try to make 1 big regex object and then switch/case the results.

Here are some examples of what the string can be:

- every day
- every weekday
- every week on sunday, monday, wednesday
- every 3 weeks on sunday, friday
- every first sunday of every month
- day 1 of every 2 months
- every january 1

I can do OK when it comes to regex but this is out of league and I'm not sure if I should use different regex objects or try to make a big one.  Thanks for any help

It looks like /\w+\s?(\d+?)?\s(\w+)/ takes care of "every week", "every day", "every month", "every year", "every 10 days", etc.

Comment: So...where's the code so far?

Comment: Not a full-on answer, so I'm leaving it as a comment. I think you should make only extremely specific checks for the strings you're expecting. This will be much clearer and to maintain. Write the full code first though, you will run into issues quickly enough so you will understand the best solution yourself.

Comment: You might be better off creating your own parser: http://pegjs.majda.cz/.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think regular expressions are going to help you much here.  They might be able to do some of the really simple matching, but what you're really looking at here is a grammar parsing problem.  You might want to read up on languages designed to express abstract grammars, like [Extended Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (EBNF).  It sounds intimidating, but it's really not that hard to grasp.  Once you're able to describe your grammar in a formal language, suddenly parsing it becomes much easier (at the very least, you have a specification of what kind of inputs are valid).  For example, you might have the following EBNF for your problem:

```
expression = "every" time-unit|time-unit-list|composite-time-unit
time-unit = { ordinal } "day" | "weekday"
ordinal = "first" | "second" | "third" | ...
```

And so on.  This is not a trivial job; parsing an English sentence, even a fairly restrictive one like this can be quite involved.  However, it is a well-established and rigorous method.

Once you've got your grammar defined, you can build a parser for it.  This is a matter of looking for *terminals* (like "every") and then matching them to a rule.  For example, you might have something like the following (pseudocode):

```
words = split(/\s*/,lowercase(input))
if( words[0] == "every" ) {
  switch( words[1] ) {
    case "first":
    case "second":
    case "third":
    ...
      parseTimeUnit(words);
      break;
    case "day":
      everyDay = true;
      break; 
    ...
  }
}
```

Depending on the complexity of your grammar, you might look into automatically generating the parser with something like [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

You've bitten yourself off a hunk of a problem, but it's a rewarding one to work through, so good luck!

**Update**: I only suggested Yacc because it's among the oldest parser generators I know of.  However, there are a million of them, and a lot of them will emit Javascript for you.  You can check out [Wikipedia's comparison of parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are trying to do [is parse a string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) into some data structure, and that I believe is not a job for regex (although it could be a part of the solution).